# how to set up dual wireless routers (G and N) with single broadband connection

Tags: wifi

A local cafe has an 802.11g wireless router attached to either an 8- or 12Mbs broadband connection.  Although many customers still have -g devices, an increasing number are showing up with 802.11n devices (e.g. Mac laptops, iPads).  The cafe owner is content with his router's area coverage, but he would like for his customers to be able to take advantage of the higher -n download speeds.

He could simply replace the -g router with a -n router, but reportedly -n routers slow down considerably when servicing both -g and -n connections.  Another option would be to buy the -n router, run an Ethernet cable between the two routers, and (of course) hook up the broadband connection to one of the two routers.  Still another option would be to attach an ordinary, wired switch to the broadband connection and then attach both routers to the switch.

Aside from the cost issue, what are the tradeoffs of those approaches?  Which would you recommend, and why?  Is there a better option than the ones I mentioned?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it doesn't matter what IP addresses cafe users get, you can nest your networks quite happily. You'd have something like

```
[internet] <---- [wireless n router 192.168.0.1] <----[wireless g router 192.168.1.1]
```

You'd run a network cable from a LAN port on the n router into the WAN port on the g router.

Note that running n isn't going to affect internet access much, as the bottleneck is the 8-12mb internet connection.

Comment: Also note that G takes up 1/3 of the bandwidth available in the 2.4GHz spectrum. N takes up the whole spectrum, so the two will overlap, and cause performance issues if you have quite a few devices on both at the same time.

Comment: You could address that by running the N router over the 5 Ghz bsnd, couldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

The easyiest solution is to use one router as gateway ( for example G router ) 
GW will run the DHCP , maybe DNS, and will take care of routing and NATing
on the N router you should disable DHCP, set IP from the range of G router and interconnect them like this :

```
LAN G <-> LAN N
```

also you need to corretly set up wifi 
- you can set up same SSID and SECURITY (client device will choose which device will prefer when connecting)
- you have to set different channels (when using 2.4GHz because of overlapping, http://www.howtogeek.com/197268/how-to-find-the-best-wi-fi-channel-for-your-router-on-any-operating-system/ this could help you); for example you can set channel 1 on G and channel 6 on N router